# MVC 3 Code First EF not regenerating my database from the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have been working with my MVC application for a few weeks now, making changes to the model and rebuilding etc. Now after a recent change to a data anotation my database was not getting regenerated dispite having the strategy in the global.asax file on Application_Start

So, I manually removed the database from sql express thinking it would create a new one when I build. Nope.

Here is my start up code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
        Models.cummins_sqldb c = new Models.cummins_sqldb();
        c.Database.Initialize(true);
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<cummins_db.Models.cummins_sqldb>());
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<cummins_db.Models.cummins_sqldb>());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

I have the connection string in the web.config file.

Any suggestion on what I might try?

Comment: What kind of changes are you making to models?

Comment: Basically I added some fields, some data annotations, and a navigation property

Comment: That is quite messy code. You can set only one initializer per context type so the first `SetInitializer` call is redundant. Call to `Database.Initialize` will execute the initialization so if your initializer is set after this call it is redundant as well. Anyway it will most probably not be the source of your problem.

Comment: Yeah, it is messy. I was trying different things. So, it was just stupidity and newbie syndrome on my part. I did not realize the EF would regenerate the database from the model the first time a controller requested it.

Answer (score 0):

something like this happened to me
typically,it happen when u have conflict in changing the table definition
for Example:
u have already some data in DB
and adding a foreign Key to table, that can not be null, to relate ur exciting table to new one

the foreign key field for data that were on the table, stay null
and it have conflict with the new table definition
solution is something like this:

```
  // Create  a department for course to point to.
Sql("INSERT INTO dbo.Department (Name, Budget, StartDate) VALUES ('Temp', 0.00, GETDATE())");
//  default value for FK points to department created above.
AddColumn("dbo.Course", "DepartmentID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 1)); 
//AddColumn("dbo.Course", "DepartmentID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
```

Tom Dykstra , have nice tutorial for solving this issue:
[getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

take look at it(at chapter 4) , hope this be a help

after that u can easily roll back the last working migration
then update data base
making some changes and again update ur data base with ur desire

> oh dude, i saw the asked date now, hope it help some one else... :))